# How to convert `const char* const` to `const char*`

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a `const char* const` which I need to pass to a method that expects a  `const char*`. How do I do that?.

Also, there is an API that accepts const char **. How do I change in this case?. I tried

const char* const abc="something;
otherAPIThatExpectsConstCharStarStar( &const_cast( abc ) ).

But on linnux this is failing with 'lValue required as '&' operator'.

Comment: Use const_cast: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast

Comment: [Um... just pass it](http://ideone.com/VNHzdU) ??

Comment: I can't see a problem with just passing it...?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to. The last `const` identifies the type of the variable which holds the string. This means that you cannot modify the variable. But you can freely assign it to some other variable or pass as an argument which doesn't need to be constant anymore.

Comment: There is an API that accepts const char **. How do I change in this case?. I tried &const_cast<const char*>( myConstCharPointer ). But on linnux this is failing with 'lValue required as '&' operator'.

Comment: @Pavan : Then copy it to temporary variable `const char *var2 = original` and pass the argument as `&var2`. I assume if the API is designed in such way, it probably assigns the value back to that variable. Forcing it with `const_cast` may easily break the things as it would overwrite something which is supposed to be constant and it can be even located in read-only memory.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to,as you can see ,when you give an argument to a method,the method will create a copy of the argument,so inside the method, it can only changes the copy,not the original one,unless you pass an address of reference, so,now you have a pointer , it must not be changed ,that's ok ,just pass it to the method, it won't be changed , as I've said.

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    void fun(const char *p)
   {
        char tt[10]="dsds";
        p=tt;
        cout<<"inside_fun"<<endl;

    }

    int main()
    {
        int i;
        char here[10]="212121";
        const char * const pp=here;
        fun(pp);
        cout<<pp<<endl;
    }
```

This is a bad style code, but it shows the point, just pass it, and change it inside the method,no problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::void setString(const char *p) {
    std::cout << p << std::endl;

}

int main() {
    const char* const cStr ="hello";
    setString(cStr);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: @BenjaminW. : Ohh okay! I will take care of this next time.